# I am trying to build my first andriod game but I keep getting this error about the Android SDK, NDK and tools even after doing manual install

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to build my first android game but I keep seeing this and getting a warning.
[An Image of the warnings in my preferances in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWdQT.png)

I reinstalled the recent version of unity and also tried manually installing them. I have selected the android versions of 9 and above.

Comment: Also- I don't see any option to install them in the unity hub either.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/AddModules.html

Comment: UnityHub -> Installs -> your version -> settings button on right side -> Add Modules -> Android Build support

Comment: Android Build Support and the two dropdowns SDK & NDK Tools and OpenJDK are already marked as installed.